# Load values from file in soapui community edition

Tags: soapui

Is it possible to load values from a text file in soapui. I am able to load the property file, wanted to know if it is possible to load values from text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added groovy script test step to load the values from file, as data source option is not available in the community edition.